# Java - Why that URL == null

Tags: java, url, null, initialization

Welcome, i have problem with my code. The URL that shoud hold the path to resources is not initialized can anyone help me with solving that problem? Here is a code of my loading class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class bufferedImageLoader 
{

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String pathRelativeToThis) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pathRelativeToThis);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        return img;
    }

}
```

And errors i am getting, are like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at rpg.bufferedImageLoader.loadImage(bufferedImageLoader.java:12)
    at rpg.character.draw(character.java:40)
    at rpg.main.paint(main.java:210)
    at rpg.main.update(main.java:190)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: pathRelativeToThis==null here

Comment: are you sure your path is correct?

Comment: a common error in this case is to forget the `/` at the beginning of the path (even if the path is relative!). If your resource is in the same directory as your class, the path should be `/myResource.png`.

Comment: Closed, i dont know how could i be so stiupd and was trying for 2 days to slove these with others methods... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Te method [Class.getResource(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) loads the named resource based on the class loader of the class instance.

What this normally means, unless a custom classloaded loaded the class instance, is that the resource you are trying to load should be relative to your classpath.

For example, if you had the following structure on the file system:

```
C:\
+ temp
  + some-directory
    + some-other-directory
      + some-file.txt
```

And you added `C:\temp\some-directory` to the classpath, you could get the URL to `some-file.txt` using [Class.getResource(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
URL someFileUrl = someClass.getResource("/some-other-directory/some-file.txt");
```